# Multiple UPDATE STATISTICS statements in a one batch lead to error

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I generated batch to update statistics consists from multiple update stats commands. But it fail with cryptic error message. Single command can be executed successfully.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS IF EXISTS st__dim_ab_test__ab_test_key ON dwh.dim_ab_test WITH INCREMENTAL = OFF;
UPDATE STATISTICS IF EXISTS st__dim_ab_test__cust_ab_test_id ON dwh.dim_ab_test WITH INCREMENTAL = OFF;
```

[image]

[FAILED JOB ID 1](https://arkadium.azuredatalakeanalytics.net/Jobs/9e38a5cd-5648-4c15-8171-d5e82994c5d2?api-version=2015-10-01-preview)

**update**

simple queries that contain refs on u-sql tables do not work too for last 1 hour. region Central US

```
@query = SELECT * FROM [inhabit].[dwh].[dim_device] ORDER BY 1 FETCH 100;
OUTPUT @query TO "PreviewResultFolder/inhabit.dwh.dim_device_Preview.tsv" USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

[FAILED JOB ID 2](https://arkadium.azuredatalakeanalytics.net/Jobs/1ea1882b-2754-46ad-86ff-5eae85c5b782?api-version=2015-10-01-preview)

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this running just one `UPDATE STATISTICS` statement.  If you submit this job via the portal you get a link to "File a support request for this error" so I suggest you do that.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for reporting this problem. We are investigating the issue and will provide update here when we root caused it.

For time being, since you are using create stats with incremental refresh being set to OFF, you can try modifying your script to drop and recreate stat as a workaround (instead of doing update).

Script would look something like this:

```
DROP STATISTICS IF EXISTS st__dim_ab_test__ab_test_key;
DROP STATISTICS IF EXISTS st__dim_ab_test__cust_ab_test_id;
CREATE STATISTICS st__dim_ab_test__ab_test_key ON dwh.dim_ab_test;
CREATE STATISTICS st__dim_ab_test__cust_ab_test_id ON dwh.dim_ab_test;
```

hope this helps,
Igor

Comment: the problem is a few deeper. drop/creste/select are not work too for some tables... the support team is investigating it. they provided me some workarounds with set @opt = XXX and custom private runtime version. but it is not solved completely. my tech support request number is 117042615653545. when they will gave me a complete solution i will updated the topic.

Comment: the support team told me that the product team hasfixed the issue and deployed it, but i cannot check it. because the repro database has been dropped.

Comment: the support team has fixed it. the fix will be deployed at the end of month. they provided me the info.